# Cannot upgrade Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, updates

I have a Lenovo laptop and non-UEFI installation of Windows Enterprise on it. I'm stuck on version 1803. When I try to upgrade to 1909, it downloads and installs it but after reboot no OS cannot be found until I go in to BIOS and enable legacy mode. When I then log in to Windows and open Updates, it says "we couldn't install this update, but you can try again (0x80004005)". How can I upgrade Windows?

Comment: First off, who's the admin on this PC? Is it part of a company fleet or is it yours personally, and you installed Windows 10 Enterprise for some reason? If it's yours, then you may have to start from scratch, because upgrading Windows 10 Enterprise is not as easy as on the Home or Pro versions (not to mention others). It's a matter of licensing, mostly. 1803 was the last LTSC (Long Term Service Channel) version to be release in the Enterprise tier, then it was upgradable to 1809, not 1909.

Comment: Aha, it is a personal laptop. I see, then I guess I will need to reinstall Windows...